# Order a list by all item's digits in Python

Tags: python, sorting

## I want to sort a list by each item's digit.

Example:

```
myCmpItem = '511'
myList = ['111','222','333','444','555','123']

(some magic)

mySortedList = ['111', '222', '333', '123', '444', '555']
```

## How the algorithm should work:

- Compare each digit of current item in myList with myCmpItem

  - For the first item in the list it would be like that:
  - Difference between 5 and 1 is 4
  - Difference between 1 and 1 is 0
  - Difference between 1 and 1 is 0
  - Difference between those two numbers is 4 (the sum of the digit comparison)
- Do the same for all other items
- Order the list by this calculated similarity

I could code this with alot of for-loops, but I am actually looking for a faster way to do this. Is there any algorithm that does something like that? Fast?

## Further Limitations

- In my example all items have a length of 3, in the real scenario they have a length of 25
- All items have the same length, len(myList[x])==25 is always true
- Items can be strings, ints, floats or whatever fits better to the algorithm
- There are only digits between 1 and 5

## Background

All item's digits are answers to questions and I want to find the most similar answer-set to a given answer-set. So "123" means that a user answered to Questions 1 = Answer 1, Question 2 = Answer 2, Question 3 = Answer 3. They are multiple choice questions with 25 questions in total (= length of 25) and there are always 5 different possibilites to answer (Those are the digits 1-5).

*PS: This is the first question I asked on Stackoverflow so please be kind with me. I already googled for hours but I could not find any solution, so I asked here. I hope that is fine. Also english is not my native language.*

## The Answer (thanks to all participants!)

@larsmans' answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10790714/511484) explains very well how to solve this with reasonable speed. You can even speed up the algorithm by calculating the distances between every digit in advance, see @gnibbler's post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791838/511484) All the other answers were also nice and correct, but I found that @larsmans had the best explanation. Thanks everybody once again for the help!

Comment: thanks Wooble, thats what I also thought, so I used strings here

Comment: what if the difference is negative?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary its a relative distance so the sign can be skipped (abs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make a list of integers from `myCmpItem` to make subtraction possible.

```
myCmpItem = map(int, myCmpItem)
```

Then, define a function that calculates the distance between an item and `myCmpItem`. We need to map the items to lists of integers as well. The rest is just the vanilla formula for [L1 distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) (the mathematical name of the "difference" you're computing).

```
def dist(item):
    item = map(int, item)
    return sum(abs(item[i] - myCmpItem[i]) for i in xrange(len(item)))
```

Then, use this function as a `key` function for sorting.

```
sorted(myList, key=dist)
```

<del>(PS: are you sure L1 distance makes sense for this application? Using it expresses the assumption that answer 1 is more similar to answer 2 than to answer 3, etc. If that's not the case, [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) might be more appropriate.)</del>

Comment: Love it! I searched for something like that but I have never heard of the L1 distance. And you are absolutely right: answer 1 is closer to answer 2 than to answer 3. Thank you so much for that, I'll do some speedtesting now!

Comment: Oh no, does not work with int because those string-items have a length of 25 and converted to int they will actually become a long and "for i in (long)" does not work in python.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `xrange` + indexing instead of `zip`?

Comment: @MatthiasScholz, I think you've misunderstood. `map(int, '111')` returns `[1, 1, 1]`, not `111`. Nothing will become a long here.

Comment: Sorry @senderle, my fault! You were right! I accept that as the answer, its really fast! About 1 second for 100k items!

Comment: @senderle: `xrange` came to mind first. `zip` would work just as well.

Answer (score 5):

With `lambda` and list comprehension:

```
sorted(myList, key=lambda item: sum([abs(int(x) - int(y)) for x, y in zip(item, myCmpItem)])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def cmpWith(num):
    def compare(item):
        """ calculate the difference between num and item """
        return sum(
            abs(int(n) - int(x)) # cast to int to make the substraction possible
            for x,n in zip(item, num) # zip makes pairs from both lists 
        )

    return compare

lst = ['111','222','333','444','555','123']
print sorted(lst, key=cmpWith('511'))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
myCmpItem = '511'
myList = ['111','222','333','444','555','123']

def make_key(x):
    diff = 0
    for a, b in zip(x, myCmpItem):
        diff += abs(int(a)-int(b))
    return diff

mySortedList = sorted(myList, key=make_key)

print mySortedList
```

Answer (score 2):

Precomputing a table of distances may be faster than converting every digit to `int`

```
myCmpItem = '511'
myList = ['111','222','333','444','555','123']

# only need to compute this dict once
dists = {(i,j):abs(int(i)-int(j)) for i in '12345' for j in '12345'}

print sorted(myList, key=lambda j: sum(dists[i] for i in zip(j, myCmpItem)))
```

On my computer, this is 2.9 times faster than larsmans answer for 100000 x 25 character strings

Comment: This is a very nice improvement! Thanks for that!